# a html layout problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a html layout,this is the image:
[image]

The whole page contain the divs:

```
Head
left
main01
main02
```

And the control div:

```
toogle_bar1
toogle_bar2
```

Now I want to make the following effect:

1) The `head` take a specified height of the browser(for example 50px),and take 100% width of the browser.
2) And by default,the `main02` is not visible,so the `main01` div take the same height of the `left` and take the left width.

3) When the `toggle_bar1` clicked,the `left` should be hide/shown,once it is not visible,the `main01` (and `main02` if `main02` is visible) will take all the width of the browser.

4) When `toggle_bar2` clicked,the `main02` should be hidden/shown,once it is visible,it will take the same width as `main01`.

5) the `main01` and `main02` should have a explictly width and height property.
6) The scroll bar can not be visible anyway when the window resize.

In fact,I can make it using the javascript,but I wonder If I can make it using the pure css(of course the js is need to handle the click event)?

Since now I use the js,when the `toggle_bar1` clicked,I set the `left` to "display:none",then caculate the clientwidth,and set the width of the `main01`(or/and `main02`),I wonder if this can be caculated by the browser?

I always think that we should avoid do the extra position cacualte work if they can be done by the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend using YUI to do this for you.

Comment: we can not use the extra js library.

Comment: You say that main01 and main02 should have an explicit width. Do you mean percentage or discrete value? If you want to use a discrete value, what do you use to fill out the right gap (if your values are tot small). If there should not be a gap, I think percentage values are a good idea. Set width to 45% if both are visible and 90% if only one...

Comment: so using js explictly to set the width of the elemetn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add remove CSS Classes to the Main Wrapper.

Let say you have the MainWrapper and in it "Left", "Middle", "Right"

then you can add or remove CSS Classes from the MainWrapper

```
.left-item, .right-item, .middle-item { // this are the classes in the Wrapper
some base info
}

.has-left.has-middle .left-item {
width:30%;
} 
.has-left.has-middle .middle-item {
width:70%;
}
.has-left.has-middle .right-item {
display:none;
}
```

What you would have to do with the other combinations, you should know.

No you just use js to "add" or "remove" your css classes, and css does it for you. 
MainWrapper Classes: has-left, has-middle, has-right
remove one of them, and your css adjusts.

It sounds like you dont need any generic version, so this could do it...

Answer (score -1):

you could try one of these in styling:

```
a
a:link
a:focus
a:hover
a:visited
a:active
```

Maybe...